# Best practice to develop GWT (GXT) applications with Maven (3) and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

What is the best way to develop the GWT (GXT) applications using Maven3 and Eclipse with Sonatype M2Eclipse plugin.
All explanations so far are over one year old and actually the latest gwt-archetype (version 2.2) generates a significantly different pom.xml as in examples, more over features like message class generation and asynchronous interface generation (hello EJBs) are added in the meantime. I would also expect tricks and workarounds about finest Google Dev Plugin generated by latest (2.2) version of gwt-maven-plugin should be somehow used in Eclipe, but I don't understand yet how.

Renat

Answer (score 1):

Following is what I am doing ( my environment: Eclipse-3.7, GWT-2.3.0, Eclipse GWT plugin installed from the Eclipse marketplace ):

1). Create the GWT project by using the webAppCreator.cmd (see GWT_HOME directory).

```
webAppCreator.cmd -out c:\dev\workspace-3.7\GxtTest01 -maven com.company.test.GxtTest01
```

2). Import the project into Eclipse.
Eclipse->Import->Maven->Existing maven project

3). Add GXT dependency.
Since the repositories have outdated version (2.2.0) I do attach the latest version of GXT manually:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/gxt-2.2.4-gwt22.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

4). That it. Go to work with the code

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: +1 to having to use system scope to get gxt 2.2.4 dependency without localhost installing the jar. @Renat - You should accept this answer.